# How to create a dashboard for logged-in users with custom functionality?

Tags: plugins, php, uploads, javascript, plugin-recommendation

I am developing a Wordpress website in which each logged-in user should have a dashboard from which (s)he can upload video files. Each user has an upload limit of X GB. He also should be capable of seeing the amount of his remaining space. 
How should i create that dashboard? Is there a plugin or i should write my own PHP code ?

Comment: Asking for plugin recommendations are considered Off Topic. Please check out in the help section [what is On Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a Good Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Tnx.  I just don't know how to achieve this goal. I am not looking for a specific plugin. i just want to learn how to do this. Even developing a plugin or custom coding. I think it is a good question for community.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is either off-topic because you ask for plugin recomendation, or off-topic because it is too broad. Try to make a smaller question either about general design approch or relevant implementation detail, but supply much more details regarding your specific requirements and what you already tried or considered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a question that has any one particular answer. It all depends on specifically, what you are trying to achieve. You probably will not find a plugin that does exactly what you want without some heavy customization anyway, and I think that it will probably be easier to write your own plugin or custom theme functionality. I you have never done something like that before the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) is good a place to start.